# Can I convert a 64 bit Windows to 32 bit Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, conversion, 32-bit

Is it possible to convert 64 bit Windows 7 to 32 bit Windows 7 keeping the settings and installed software where they were ?

I am not interested in virtual machine based options.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your meaning of "convert"? Just keep settings and installed software? Then maybe you can. Otherwise it is barely possible, since at least all files containing machine code need to be replaced, this includes the drivers.

Comment: @Gurken Papst yeah keep settings and installed software.

Comment: @steve - edit that information into your question.

Comment: I don't understand the reason anyone would even want to do this.  All 32-bit software should run on the 32-bit version of the same operating system ( with a single exception Windows XP 64-bit Edition ) would work on a 64-bit installation.

Comment: No, it cannot be converted in either direction 64 to 32 or 32 to 64, been answered here plenty of times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Your only option is to do a clean install of 32-bit Windows.

Comment: If you think about it, it has to be this way. For example, if one of your programs has both a 32-bit and 64-bit version, the 64-bit version has been installed and not the 32-bit version. There's no way to move the program to a 32-bit OS without getting the 32-bit version somehow. And that's only in the installer.